# KeyError: 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS' when running DRF tests with mysqlclient installed

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework, pytest

I have a functioning test suite for DRF. It uses `@pytest.mark.django_db()` to access an SQL Server DB.

I now have the need to access an ancillary MySQL DB, so I installed `mysqlclient`.

**Without changing any of my source code or django settings, intalling this package alone breaks my test suite.**

Note, that the actual mysqlclient seems to work fine and allows me to access the ancillary MySQL DB.

This is the error

```
django/core/handlers/base.py(348)make_view_atomic()
    def make_view_atomic(self, view):
        non_atomic_requests = getattr(view, "_non_atomic_requests", set())
        for alias, settings_dict in connections.settings.items():
>           if settings_dict["ATOMIC_REQUESTS"] and alias not in non_atomic_requests:
E           KeyError: 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS'
```

I have tried using this: `@pytest.mark.django_db(databases=["default"])` to isolate things to the SQL Server DB.  It doesn't help.

I have tried setting ATOMIC_REQUESTS in settings and it doesn't stick.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'NAME': os.environ['DATABASE'],
        'USER': os.environ['USERNAME'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['SERVER_URL'],
        "ATOMIC_REQUESTS": True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server',
            'extra_params': "Encrypt=no" 
}}
```

In the debugger, it doesn't show 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS' in the settings.

```
ipdb> settings_dict
{'ENGINE': 'mssql', 'HOST': 'localhost', 'NAME': 'dev'}
```

Answer (score 4):

The ATOMIC_REQUESTS settings was not working because I forgot I had conftest.py overriding it.  Adding it there worked.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def django_db_setup():
    settings.DATABASES["default"] = {
        "Engine": "mssql",
        "ATOMIC_REQUESTS": True,
        "HOST": os.environ["SERVER_URL"],
        "NAME": os.environ["TEST_DATABASE"],
    }
```